# Different Power point Presentation UI on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have Powerpoint on two of my windows 10 computer but I noticed that the UI of both of them is different.

This is the picture of PC1:
[image: one of them(PC1)]

And this one is of PC2:
[image: Other(PC2)]

I might add that I have no subscription in either of them. Also I remember that some time ago, the UI of PowerPoint(of PC1) had changed (to that of PC2) after I had updated the windows (of PC1) But it again went back to the old one.

I really like the UI of the office apps of PC2 . Is there any way I can get it for PC1?

Comment: What versions are they? I suspect one is 2016, the other is 2019.

Comment: It says "Microsoft Home and Student 2019" for the first. Other one is also 2019

Comment: This is a known issue with ribbon being different in upgrade vs fresh install situations, as far as I remember. They are trying a new version of the ribbon, somewhat stealthily. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ribbon-in-office-had-change-to-bigger-space/12495ff6-ac28-4a11-a1db-36ad0d751d8d or https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-2016-ribbons-have-all-changed/b65023b4-64fd-4386-a6f0-fb812e502c56 for instance.

Comment: More obscurely, the difference may show only in some apps https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/493188/excel-2019-ribbon-updated-to-the-new-office-365-st.html